# how to change nginx error page?

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

I use AWS ec2 ami and nginx and node.js express

how to change nginx err page html or ejs??

like express error handler...

my nginx server block

```
server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  localhost;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
         proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
         proxy_redirect off;
        }

error_page 404 http://example.com/error;
error_page 500 502 503 504 http://example.com/error;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have a custom error page for 404 and 50x errors :

First save your custom error pages in the /usr/share/nginx/html directory which is   Nginx's default document root. 
Create a page for 404 errors called customerror_404.html and one for 50x errors say customerror_50x.html.

> > echo " This is not the page you looking for!! Error 404 " | sudo tee /usr/share/nginx/html/customerror_404.html

similarly for customerror_50x.html file.

Nginx defaults must be aware of to use these custom files
so open nginx default,

> > vi /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ;
    server_name  localhost;
     # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
    . . .

    error_page 404 /customerror_404.html;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    location = /customerror_404.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            internal;
    }
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /customerror_50x.html;
    location = /customerror_50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            internal;
    }

}
```

save the file and restart nginx 
test the changes : 
http://server_hostname_or_IP/anynonexistingfilename

You are good to go.

Comment: ok thx! i have try /etc/nginx/nginx.conf append  this code is not working but error_page upon append proxy_intercept_errors on; this code is working! 
Why it works?? @Shashi Bhushan

Comment: proxy_intercept_errors on | off;
Determines whether proxied responses with codes greater than or equal to 300 should be passed to a client or be intercepted and redirected to nginx for processing with the error_page directive. 
Ref: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors

Comment: Great that your problem resolved. @young 

And this directive defines nginx interception of HTTP responses.
 By default all responses will be sent as-is from the proxied server.

By setting this "on" , nginx will intercept status codes that are explicitly handled by an error_page directive. All other Responses with non-defined status codes will be sent as it is from the proxied server.